# What's the function of "a" in "a mere three years later"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article, determiners, functions

> The Supreme Court overruled this decision **a mere three years later**. (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minersville_School_District_v._Gobitis))

Is using an indefinite article "a" to determine **three years** grammatical? If so, why? Also, is *a* used here as part of a collocation with "mere"? Can I replace *mere* with a different adjective?

Comment: See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/indefinite-articles-used-with-plural-nouns-it-was-an-amazing-two-days) and *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum 2002), p.352.

Comment: @userr2684291 Very helpful. Thank you! I have just read Huddleston & Pullum 2002 p.352-354. I guess my example sentence falls under "dependents that select a singular or quantified plural head." **A mere** is not on the list, but I think it is comparable to **a good**.

Comment: Sure thing. And yes, that appears to be the case. If you read the accepted answer to the linked question, you'll find an article (*Funky a*) in which M. Liberman (a linguist) talks about this, and even they're not sure... Okay, I don't want to repeat stuff, so see https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45067857#45067857. I summed up the bits I'm not sure about there. Hopefully that won't confuse you further. Oh, and, you'll find an article in which another linguist (a co-author of CGEL) tells us they don't know how to analyze article + adjective + name, about which you also asked.

Comment: (There wasn't really a discussion there, just a bunch of links you should probably check out.) But anyway, read the whole thing in CGEL and some things will be clearer regarding determiners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "a" goes with "mere", not with "three years" (and yes, it's grammatical).

You could replace "a mere" with "only" or "just":

> The Supreme Court overruled this decision just three years later.

When used with small quantities, the indefinite article is often coupled with *mere*. [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mere) lists several examples:

> - It took her a mere 20 minutes to win.
> - A mere 2% of their budget was spent on publicity.
> - He seemed so young, a mere boy.
> - You've got the job. The interview will be a mere formality.

The word *mere* is not unique in this regard; the word **[*paltry*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/paltry?q=paltry)** is often structured the same way:

> - This account offers a paltry 1% return on your investment.

Note: The article would not be used if *merely* was used in place of *a mere*:

> It took her merely 20 minutes to arrive.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. I have heard "a mere 20 dollars", so I thought it might be case that _a_ and _mere_ go hand in hand. Just to clarify: is _a_ still a determiner here? I now understand from your answer the indefinite article has everything to do with _mere_ and not much with _three years_, but does it still determine _three years_?